# Android Alert Dialog replace default blue with another color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I'm using a single choice alert dialog in which I'd like to replace the default blue (the title line and the radio buttons) to the orange that I am using in the title bar. I was able to change to the title bar using `setCustomTitle()`, but I am lost trying to get rid of this damn blue.

**For the title bar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/orange" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Alert Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

**Building the AlertDialog**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
View customTitle = View.inflate(MainActivity.this, R.layout.custom_alert_title, null);
builder.setCustomTitle(customTitle);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mAlertOptions, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                    
        // do stuff
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}).create().show();
```

**This is what it looks like**

[image]

I need to get rid of this blue! Help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only way to change the title divider color is to use `Resources.getIdentifier` in combination with `Window.findViewById`. The checkmark can be easily changed by calling `AlertDialog.Builder.setSingleChoiceItems(ListAdapter, int, OnClickListener)`.

Here's an example:

**Single choice item layout**
: I generated `your_radio_button` using [Android Holo Colors.](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/your_radio_button"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingEnd="16dip"
    android:paddingStart="16dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorAlertDialogListItem" />
```

**Implementation**

```
    final ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                    "Option 1", "Option 2"
            });

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCustomTitle(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_title, null));
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do something
        }
    });

    // Show the AlertDialog
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

    // Change the title divider
    final Resources res = getResources();
    final int titleDividerId = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
    final View titleDivider = dialog.findViewById(titleDividerId);
    titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! One last thing, do you know how to get rid of the blue highlight that flashes when the row is clicked? That seems to be the last of the blue.

Comment: @Kelvin_TA add this attribute to the checkedTextView android: background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground. But remember that you must set clickable and focusable attribute to true for it to work by adding android:clickable="true". android:focusable="true"